# How to take down a static network interface when not connected?

Tags: debian, networking, networkmanager

I have 2 network interfaces:

- eth0 for LAN connection
- wlan2 for wireless connection

I have set them static in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file. The problem is that I rarely have both connected at the same time and if the LAN is not connected, wlan2 doesn't work until I take down the eth0 manually with `ifconfig`.

Why does this happen?

I would like that when one interface is not connected it will be turned off automatically. How can I do that?

Here's the interfaces file:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.130
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
up route add default gw 192.168.1.10 eth0
down route del default gw 192.168.1.10 eth0

auto wlan2
iface wlan2 inet static
wpa-ssid "dlink"
wpa-key-mgmt WPA-PSK
wpa-psk wpapass

address 192.168.1.150
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
up route add default gw 192.168.1.20 wlan2
down route del default gw 192.168.1.20 wlan2
```

NetworkManager.conf

```
[main]
 plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
 managed=true
```

Comment: "0 down vote favorite"?

Comment: sorry I made a mistake :)

Comment: Do you have NetworkManager running? It should be handling this for you automatically. I have a similar setup with a eth0 and wlan0 and it switches back and forth just fine.

Comment: yes I have NetworkManeger running

Comment: it seems that networkManager can handle only non-eth0 interfaces in that way. So if I don't connect the wifi then it rightly doesn't enable the wlan interface. Moreover, the wlan gateway is never added.

Comment: @Gappa did you always have managed=true set, or did you just set that? If you just set it, you probably need to restart Network Manager for it to take effect.

Comment: [Do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). I've voted to close on [so] since this doesn't appear to be programming-related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you configure a wired network using `/etc/network/interfaces`, you tell Network Manager not to touch it. There is some documentation of this in the [Debian Wiki NetworkManager](http://wiki.debian.org/NetworkManager#Wired_Networks_are_Unmanaged) article.

So, to make it work, your best bet is probably to remove (or comment out) your configuration in /etc/network/interfaces (except for lo) and entirely use Network Manager. You'll probably want to make them system connections, so they can be up before you log in.

Alternatively, you could set `managed=true` as shown in the wiki.

Comment: if you use Network Manager, will the interfaces be configured in single user mode?

Comment: @Sparr (Assuming here you're talking about the option labeled recovery in grub): Not by default, but you could change that by changing Network Manager's run levels (to make it start in S), or just run it with `/etc/init.d/network-manager start`. It also won't work with a NFS-mounted /usr, but I assume that doesn't exist here.

Comment: I have added the network manager conf file

Comment: I'm sorry but how can I know if the interfaces are configured in single user mode?

Comment: @Gappa well, you'd boot into single user and check. I doubt its a huge issue, though, as you can just bring it up using NetworkManager or manually if you need to recover the system.

Comment: @Gappa I have confirmed that if you just comment out all your network configuration in /etc/network/interfaces, and configure everything through Network Manager, it works. At least, it does on my virtual machine. Down the interface with `ifdown`, comment it out, then `/etc/init.d/network-manager restart`

Comment: @derobert Thank you, I will try that way. I will keep you posted.

Comment: @derobert it works perfectly, thank you very much!!!