# Emulate unplugging a network cable with qemu-kvm

Tags: networking, virtualization, kvm, qemu, libvirt

*[Background: I'd like to actually test [How to take down a static network interface when not connected?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81016/how-to-take-down-a-static-network-interface-when-not-connected/81031) ]*

I'm setting up a QEMU-KVM virtual machine using libvirt (via `virt-manager`). I put two NICs on it (both virtio). They are bridged to a physical NIC on the host.

I want to test what NetworkManager does when I "unplug" one. But there isn't button/checkbox for that in virt-manager, nor a quick Google search turn up anything.

How do I emulate unplugging the network cable?

Comment: virt-manager is not the best GUI ever made...

Comment: @HaukeLaging that is definitely true!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can do that in the console with:

```
virsh domif-setlink domain interface-device state
```

And check its status with:

```
virsh domifstat domain interface-device
```

You can see the network interfaces configured with:

```
virsh domifaddr domain
```

Have a look at the man page for details.

---

Here's an example of a typical workflow:

```
$ sudo virsh list
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
 24    ubuntu17.10                    running

$ sudo virsh domifaddr ubuntu17.10
 Name       MAC address          Protocol     Address
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 vnet0      52:54:00:d0:76:cb    ipv4         192.168.122.183/24

$ sudo virsh domif-getlink ubuntu17.10 vnet0
vnet0 up
$ sudo virsh domif-setlink ubuntu17.10 vnet0 down
Device updated successfully

$ sudo virsh domif-getlink ubuntu17.10 vnet0
vnet0 down
$ sudo virsh domif-setlink ubuntu17.10 vnet0 up  
Device updated successfully

$ sudo virsh domif-getlink ubuntu17.10 vnet0
vnet0 up
```

Comment: The version of virsh I have on my distro is pretty old (1.2.2) and doesn't have the `domifaddr` command. I had to use `domiflist` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the advice at https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/qemu-discuss/2017-01/msg00103.html, you can plug/unplug a cable in the qemu  console using `set_link <name> on|off`.

`info network` shows you the available network links.

Comment: Do you know if `set_link` in the qemu console (monitor?) has the same effect as `virsh domif-setlink` in the other answer?